# Survey Permissions

Tags: permissions, survey

I created a survey for our internal customers to rate employees in my group.

I need to set the permissions so the users can fill out the survey but I do not want the users to see each others responses as some may contain critical analysis and comments.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Go to Survey settings --> Advanced Settings and Check **Read responses that were created by the user** [image]